# Ruby yield newbie issue

Tags: ruby, yield

I have recently started using Ruby, so quite new to this. My current objective is to use a ruby module called retort, my problem is that I don't understand the configure method which is looking like this:

```
def configure
    config = Config.new
    yield config
    @@service = XMLRPC::Client.new2(config.url)
end
```

Config class is simple and looks like:

```
class Config
    attr_accessor :url
end
```

I tried to create a small example to play around in order to understand how exactly that is supposed to work:

```
class TestClass
  def test_method
     config = String.new
     yield config
     p config
  end
end

d = TestClass.new
d.test_method { 'test string' }
```

Of course it doesn't return 'test string' but an empty string.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be clearer about what's confusing you? Does this code make sense to you?

```
class TestClass
  def test_method
    config = yield
    p config
  end
end

d.test_method { "test string" }
```

The `yield` statement invokes the block. The block returns a string, which is assigned to the `config` variable back in the `test_method` and is then printed. Does that make it clearer?

In your code, the line `yield config` is invoking the block while passing in the just-instantiated `Config` object. For instance:

```
def foo
  s = "a string"
  yield s
  p "In foo printing " + s
end

foo { |x| p "In block printing " + x }
```

Comment: This makes it clearer yes, thanks Larry. However I still struggle with that configure methode and config object. What doest the "yield config" exactly do? And how can I define the config that way?

Comment: The `yield config` passes the just-created `Config` object to the block. Like, let's say that the block was `configure { | c | c.url = "http://google.com" }` ... The `Config` in the block would be passed to the block, which could assign to it's `url` field, and then the flow of control comes back into the `configure` method with its url assigned. (And passes it to the XMLRPC Client, etc.)